# How to make a horizontally scrollable (on mobile) menu bar?

Tags: php, html, css

I don't have much skill on coding. So I's like to know how to make exactly like this menu bar on Google with css and html?
[Click here to see sample image of Google menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu9dN.jpg)

FYI: I have found this.. is it the same?

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 14px">
    menu1 | menu2 | menu3 | menu4 | menu5 | menu6 | menu7 | menu8
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried anything? look at their HTML source and take it from there.

Comment: I have tried before but not working. (I don't have much experience with css and html)

Comment: Then show us what you did.

Comment: a nice HTML/CSS 101 course would work in your favor.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)! You need to try to write the code **yourself**. After doing [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and you still have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of **what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @BenHarson - you tell us. Did you try it? Did it work? If yes, you can use it. If no, you should search again.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a div with no elements inside of it to represent your navbar. That text inside the div doesn't mean anything. Try something more like this you want to use `<a>` tags:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

a {
  margin-right: 14px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:not(:last-of-type):after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 14px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -7px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 6</a>
</nav>
```